# Correspondence principle for macroscopic orbits

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, semiclassical

According to the correspondence principle, quantum laws ought to reduce to classical ones in the limit of macroscopic bodies, right?

But I don't see how the probability clouds of electrons in orbitals in an atom could ever reduce to something like the orbits of macroscopic bodies. Can somebody tell me how this may be done?

Comment: Work out the parameters of a hydrogen-like atomic state with very high $n$ and $l$ (corresponding to significant angular momentum).

Comment: @dmckee I haven't seen the Schrodinger equation solved for hydrogen atom, so if somebody could write that and the limit for high $n$ and $l$ as an answer, that would be awesome

Comment: @dmckee  It also needs coherent states to make the connection between probability clouds over the whole sphere (or circles) and a more localized "particle". For OP, a 1D animation can be seen here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_states#The_wavefunction_of_a_coherent_state